# ModuleController: has no selected Controller - test was shutdown as a consequence

Tags: jmeter

[Script Taxonomy][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r5S5.jpg

**Attached is a picture that talks as to how scripts are structured for our testing needs.**

We have a Jmeter project (e.g.Main.JMX) with multiple thread groups as shown in the pic and each thread group is calling external JMX (e.g.Sub1.jmx, Sub2.jmx) using the include controller. In each external JMX file (e.g.Sub1.jmx, Sub2.jmx), we have created a thread group, that contains simple controllers with a series of steps that is representing a test case. Each step from the simple controller is calling the test fragment residing in the same Sub1.JMX using the module controller.

The module controller defined in the simple controller is failing to locate the test fragments and producing the below error from Sub1.JMX file.

Error occurred starting thread group :[TG]-Subscriptions, error message:ModuleController:[MC]-2. Login to portal/mobile has no selected Controller (did you rename some element in the path to target controller?), test was shutdown as a consequence,
see log file for more details

rg.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopTestException: ModuleController:[MC]-2. Login to portal/mobile has no selected Controller (did you rename some element in the path to target controller?), test was shutdown as a consequence
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.ModuleController.resolveReplacementSubTree(ModuleController.java:143) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.ModuleController.restoreSelected(ModuleController.java:126) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.ModuleController.clone(ModuleController.java:70) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.TreeCloner.addNodeToTree(TreeCloner.java:76) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.TreeCloner.addNode(TreeCloner.java:63) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:993) ~[jorphan.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:994) ~[jorphan.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:994) ~[jorphan.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:994) ~[jorphan.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:994) ~[jorphan.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:976) ~[jorphan.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup.cloneTree(ThreadGroup.java:535) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup.makeThread(ThreadGroup.java:310) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup.startNewThread(ThreadGroup.java:265) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup.start(ThreadGroup.java:244) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.startThreadGroup(StandardJMeterEngine.java:527) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:452) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]

Please advise if there is any possibility to get rid of the above error achieve the successful connection between the module controller defined in the simple controller and the test fragment (in Sub1.jmx).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using simplified test plan assuming:

1. `Sub1.jmx` test plan with [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) pointing to that Test Fragment
2. `Main.jmx` test plan with [Include Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) pointing to `Sub1.jmx`

[image]

So most probably you either forgot to "select" the necessary test fragment in the Module Controller or renamed the Test Fragment after selecting so the Module Controller cannot find its target anymore.

If I'm reading your question incorrectly and the problem is still there I would ask to provide a minimal reproducible example test plan(s) based on [Debug Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)

Also be informed that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always use the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so you can try upgrading as it might be the case you're suffering from a JMeter bug which has already been fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let's assume that test fragments are organized in sub1.JMX project with more than 1 fragment (say fragment 1, fragment2). The tests are constructed in a way that the thread group is invoking both fragments. when you run the tests from Main. JMX, the tests are not executing if it points to fragment2.